# Wordpress blog redirect to another URL from google search engine result

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My website is [www.padmavatiwealth.com](http://www.padmavatiwealth.com). When I reach directly to this website then It is working fine but when I go through google search engine It redirects me to another strange website. I used wordpress to develop this website. I don't understand what is happening here.

Please help me. Below is google URL which redirects me to another URL, instead of padmavatiwealth.com.

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=padmavatiwealth.com&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.padmavatiwealth.com%2F&ei=Wl2bUI3YH4yqrAfyjIHwDw&usg=AFQjCNE8ifN9KNmcMjPYwAAoZe0NjsvfgQ

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just checked, Got your problem I recently solved this for my client, This is nothing to do with .htacces, let me know if you need help professionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had similar issue myself today.

The problem was a malicious plugin. Even after removing the plugin the issue remained.

The .htaccess file was being over written to include a redirect.

I removed the redirect and re uploaded it

Your .htaccess should simply look something like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Make sure your .htaccess file only has read permissions 0444

Answer (score 0):

Most logical explanation: You have installed a malicious plugin (or still have it installed) that detects the google bot and redirects accordingly to get more visits to their site.

Best way to proceed. Set up a new wordpress environent. Copy the wp-config.php from the old one to the new one. Copy template/plugins one by one and keep checking.

You can also use one of the many browser addons that let you fake your user agent, that way your browser will be able to look like the google bot, so you can see if the redirect returns or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me those addon's name?

Comment: No i can't .. there are tons of crap plugins that do crap stuff with your wordpress blog. Especially when testing plugins stuff can get really messed up. Its allways a good idea to test plugins in a seperate environment and keep an eye out for changes in the wordpress code (i.e. check for modification dates on the wordpress files)